# How do I convert an array of objects to a specified object format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, immutable.js

This is some example data that I have access to in an array.

```
[
{ filesList: List {size: 2, _origin: 0, _capacity: 2, _level: 5, _root: null, …},
id: "089b5559-171f-46b0-9aa4-1c9fc5013b0b",
name: "Arabidopsis TAIR10",
value: "Arabidopsis",
},
{ filesList: List {size: 2, _origin: 0, _capacity: 2, _level: 5, _root: null, …},
id: "da8f7da3-04e3-4aba-98e3-615e86982a60",
name: "Arabidopsis TAIR10",
value: "Arabidopsis",
},
{ filesList: List {size: 2, _origin: 0, _capacity: 2, _level: 5, _root: null, …},
id: "6b166a90-f73b-4000-b18c-8f7b80513e6d",
name: "Bean GCF_000499845.1",
value: "Bean_reference_genome",
}
]
```

Here is an example of the `filesList` object. It is an array.

```
List {size: 2, _origin: 0, _capacity: 2, _level: 5, _root: null, …}
size: 2
__altered: false
__hash: undefined
__ownerID: undefined
_capacity: 2
_level: 5
_origin: 0
_root: null
_tail: VNode
array: Array(2)
0: File
id: "92cb45c3-91ec-4e1e-8ead-99762465f9e2"
isLocal: true
lastModified: 1591716051955
lastModifiedDate: Tue Jun 09 2020 10:20:51 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
name: "Gene_List_edgr_chickpea.txt"
size: 162890
type: "text/plain"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
1: File
id: "edccae34-71dd-46f7-a4e1-d821e1315f1a"
isLocal: true
lastModified: 1591716038452
lastModifiedDate: Tue Jun 09 2020 10:20:38 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
name: "callset_name_hc.g.vcf.gz"
size: 3891432
type: "application/x-gzip"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
ownerID: OwnerID {}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: IndexedCollection
```

I need to convert this information to an object that is structured below.

With each key being the value from the Object. If the key value is duplicate I want to append the filesList data to the same key.

```
{ 
Arabidopsis: [file1, file2, file3, file4],
Bean_reference_genome: [file1, file2]
}
```

How could I go about achieving this data structure?

Comment: Could you please show a full example of the `filesList` object?

Comment: @Paul I have updated with the object

Comment: Try my solution - just the expression, not my object. I think it's already working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the structure of `filesList`. If it contains some simple js array, it would look quite similiar to the following.

```js
const data = [{
    filesList: {
      size: 2,
      _origin: 0,
      _capacity: 2,
      _level: 5,
      _root: null,
      array: ["abc", "cde"]
    },
    id: "089b5559-171f-46b0-9aa4-1c9fc5013b0b",
    name: "Arabidopsis TAIR10",
    value: "Arabidopsis",
  },
  {
    filesList: {
      size: 2,
      _origin: 0,
      _capacity: 2,
      _level: 5,
      _root: null,
      array: ["ghi", "jkl"]
    },
    id: "da8f7da3-04e3-4aba-98e3-615e86982a60",
    name: "Arabidopsis TAIR10",
    value: "Arabidopsis",
  },
  {
    filesList: {
      size: 2,
      _origin: 0,
      _capacity: 2,
      _level: 5,
      _root: null,
      array: ["qwe", "ert"]
    },
    id: "6b166a90-f73b-4000-b18c-8f7b80513e6d",
    name: "Bean GCF_000499845.1",
    value: "Bean_reference_genome",
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  acc[entry.value] = (acc[entry.value] || []).concat(entry.filesList.array);
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(result);
```

Comment: The Object with the correct keys have been created but all elements in the array that it contains are undefined.

See image:

https://imgur.com/a/Aqkclpe

Comment: Paul, OP is using immutable-js (I'm sure.  The class he's referring to matches property to property).  https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/  if you want to work with native arrays you need to call `.toArray()`

Comment: @user120242Yes that was exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewChan are you sure you want to switch to native arrays?  If you're working on a team project or for a company, undermining their use of ImmutableJS to enforce and normalize immutable types may cause problems.

Comment: @user120242 Thanks! I didn't know immutableJS before :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way of doing it. I'm assuming that you want an object where the key is the `name` and the value is the `fileList`.

```
var betterStructure = {};
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    let {name, filesList} = array[i];
    if(betterStructure.hasOwnProperty(name)){
        betterStructure[name] = betterStructure[name].concat(filesList);
    }
    else{
        betterStructure[name] = filesList;
    }
};
```

Edit: Made the logic that handles duplicates.

Comment: It's about merging the filesList object for entrys with the same value.

Comment: I edited my original answer. Hope it helps you this time.